# Is there any good solution to resolve cross-reference between two class in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, ipc, cross-reference

My use case is following

```
class Caller
{
  init(){ Callee.init(); }
  callMeByCalle() { /*do something*/ }
}

class Callee
{
  init(){ /*initialize to receive IPC call from another process*/ }
  onHandlerIPC { /*call A class's callMeByCalle() in here*/ }
}
```

Maybe I can pass the instance of A class when I call init() of Callee.
But I think it could cause a cross-reference problem.
Is there any formal or famous solution for this situation?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: there are ways to "make it work", but I would first consider if you can fix the design. Imho mutual dependency is something to be avoided

Comment: @NathanOliver The question is not clear on it, but given that it's tagged `design-patterns`, I don't think we are talking about a compiler error here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I get that.  That point remains that it shows how two classes can use each other in a way that it will compile.

Comment: Isn't that an application of IOC (Inversion Of Control)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am looking for good pattern.